# Anyone still use or be familiar with the rz and sz command?

Tags: serial-port

Background:

I used to use `putty` as my ssh client and `WinScp` as my `client <--> server` file transfer application under Windows. But after I joined the current company, I've been told by my colleagues to use the `rz` and `sz` commands to upload and downloads files to and from the cloud servers. They use `Xshell` as their ssh clients because `rz` and `sz` are available in `Xshell` but not in `putty`.

Why not using command line `scp` or `Winscp` client? Because only serveral computers inside the company's network can directly `ssh` and `scp` to the cloud servers. So when I am at home, I `ssh` to a server called **jumpserver** and then I choose which cloud server I wish to connect to, after which I can use `rz` and `sz` for file transfer.

So my question is:

How does `rz` and `sz` works internally? How does `rz` and `sz` work under my condition when `scp` and `ssh` directly to the remote servers are not available?

(A brief introduction would be much appreciated, I read the docs (`man rz`, `man rz`) and everything I can find with Google but I don't find anything helpful. I also took a glance at the [source code](https://github.com/jnavila/lrzsz) but couldn't get anything too.)

Are `rz` and `sz` reliable? Does anyone still use that? Is there a better solution for my need?

I feel pretty scared when I am using something old and unpopular like this. I don't know where things could go wrong. I always do a `sha256sum` after I upload or download files, this is driving me crazy.

I've tried some options of those 2 commands in `Xshell`, for example:

- `sz` by default sending binary, specifies `--ascii` would does line break conversion.
- `rz` always sending binary, specifiying `--ascii` doesn't change anything, which doesn't match the doc at all. ;(

Comment: In the ZMODEM protocol, the sender specifies the transfer mode (ascii vs. binary) to use. That's why specifying `--ascii` to the `rz` command does nothing: if you want ASCII mode, you must specify it in the sending end.

Comment: @telcoM sender? If I `rz` upload a file, isn't `rz` the sender? Btw, where did you get that detail? I didn't find that in the doc.

Comment: [The ZMODEM protocol description](http://gallium.inria.fr/~doligez/zmodem/zmodem.txt), page 9: "Now, transfer options may be specified to/by the sending
program, which passes them to the receiving program in the ZFILE header." It was linked on the ZMODEM Wikipedia page. And as `man rz` can tell you, `rz` means "Receive ZMODEM". What might confuse you is that you're giving that command to the *remote cloud server*, which will then send back a special string that is recognizable to a ZMODEM-capable terminal emulator (Xshell), which can then automatically activate the local "send file" function.

Comment: @telcoM Well. I saw an "send files as ASCII" option after I `rz` on the server. Screenshot is here: https://i.imgur.com/N0T3uHK.jpg . But the line ending conversion still won't happen. There is also a setting in "Session Properities" in Xshell, the default is shown in the image https://i.imgur.com/MhjsTmg.jpg. I tried modifying that to `sz -a` but still doesn't work. I think I would give up on this and take everything as binary transfer . ;P

Comment: For those who vote to close, why doesn't this question meets Unix & Linux? I think it's the only place I can seek for help. `rz` and `sz` are old stuffs but now I am using it every day. I can not find informative docs but only protocol doc which is hard to read and understand. Maybe my question isn't focused enough but it is just too much aspects as I mentioned in the question body to concern about.

Answer (score 4):

> How does rz and sz works internally?

They just basically use the terminal connection to talk to each other, and send the file over that, using a particular protocol. That involves some synchronisation (as in that the `sz` program doesn't just dump the data over the moment you start it), metadata handling (e.g. the file name) and error detection and resending when necessary. Also they seem to do some terminal setup, probably to prevent any possible control characters from being interpreted in a way that would interfere with the transfer.

I don't know the actual details of the protocol, though, but there are some links in the [ZMODEM page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) if you're interested.

Probably some of the things they do aren't really necessary over an SSH connection. E.g. with TCP/IP and Ethernet, there are error detection codes on the lower levels and TCP handles resends, and also any authenticated encryption suites on the SSH level should at least detect transmission errors (as they'd show as just like maliciously modified packets).

You can send a file over an SSH connection just with

```
cat somefile.txt | ssh me@somewhere 'cat > somefile.txt'
```

This just dumps the data over the SSH connection, which works fine since SSH is 8-bit clean and, when used like that, it doesn't set up a terminal on the remote end so terminal controls aren't a problem.

Of course, if you need to manually run the SSH client on the intermediate jump host, like

```
myworkstation$ ssh me@jumphost
jumphost$ ssh me@destination
```

Then it's a bit harder to set up the pipeline, you'd have to do something like

```
myworkstation$ cat somefile.txt | ssh me@jumphost 'ssh me@destination "cat > somefile.txt"'
```

and I'm not sure if that nested command line works with SSH. So in that sense, if both ends can use ZMODEM, it seems a somewhat usable alternative, since it's at least made to be used in the middle of a terminal session.

Then again, SSH has the `ProxyCommand` feature, which simplifies using jump hosts, and might make it easier to use just `scp` or `sftp`. See e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

> Are rz and sz reliable? Does anyone still use that? Is there a better solution for my need?
>
> I feel pretty scared when I am using something old and unpopular like this. I don't know where things could go wrong. I always do a sha256sum after I upload or download files, this is driving me crazy.

Well, they've been used since ages, and files are still (mostly) just 8 bits-per-byte dumps of data, so there's no reason they shouldn't basically still work. They are a bit archaic though, but that's not wrong per se. Performance is another question, of course, and if you find a bug, you may want to prepare for having a hard time finding an active maintainer to fix it.

Even though it's usually not needed, I'm not sure if manually verifying data transfers is such a bad thing to do anyway, if you value your data and want to be sure. If you transfer something over HTTP, you can still get a cut transfer, e.g. both `wget http://...` and `curl -o http://...` seem to be happy to leave a partial file if they get interrupted... (Same applies to the `cat | ssh cat` I presented above, mind you.)

As for what's best for your need, you'll have to decide for yourself.

Comment: I tried `ssh -J rick@jumphost:36001 jump-user@server2.example.org:36000` but didn't work.  The error is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. The jump host is not a free host I can control. It's something restricted which I can only select servers to connect to after I `ssh` into the jump server, so I can't tell where goes wrong. Maybe port forwarding is not allowed for the jump or something else, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's confirm that we're using the words `upload` and `download` the same way.

On modem connections, "upload" meant "send a file from your local system to the remote one", and "download" was "have the remote system send a file to me". I don't really know where the "up" and "down" came from - perhaps from a hierarchy of systems where individual small PCs (or even terminals) were the lowest tier, and big central computers were considered to be "higher up".

The Xshell has its own built-in implementation of the ZMODEM protocol - it does not actually use the `sz` and `rz` commands locally.

[image: The "Upload Command" option in Xshell]

The "Upload Command" option determines which command is *sent by the Xshell to the remote system* if you just use Xshell's "send file using ZMODEM" function without any preparations at the remote cloud server end. So when Xshell sends, the cloud server must receive, hence the upload command is `rz`.

For this to work, the Xshell session to the cloud server must be at command prompt, ready to receive commands. Otherwise (if you e.g. have `top` running in your session and attempt to send a file using ZMODEM) it will just garble the `top` display and hang for maybe a minute or so before telling you that the remote end failed to start receiving.

You can also just type `rz` on the cloud server's command prompt, telling the cloud server to prepare receiving a file into the directory you're currently `cd`'d in. If you do that, `rz` will output its special string, which is recognized by Xshell, and then Xshell will automatically pop up its "send file" dialog and start the transfer once you've told it which file(s) to send. (The ZMODEM protocol is designed so that if the sending side sends the "upload command" string while the receiving side has the ZMODEM already ready to receive, the unneeded command gets ignored automatically.)

If you want to transfer files the other way, for example if you have a `config-backup.zip` at the cloud server you would like to get to your local computer, you can just type `sz config-backup.zip` on the SSH session with the cloud server. The cloud server will start the `sz` (Send Zmodem) command, which will output another special string. In this case, Xshell will probably start receiving the file right away, and either will save it to a configured download directory, or ask you where the file should be placed on your local system once it's been downloaded - or even while it's still downloading.

At least on my Debian 10 system, the man page for `rz` also covers the `rx` and `rb` commands, and the man page for `sz` also covers `sx` and `sb`. The `--ascii` conversions are specified differently in each man page:

On the `rz` man page, the description of the `--ascii` option is:

> ```
>  -a, --ascii
>          Convert  files to Unix conventions by stripping carriage returns
>          and all characters beginning with the first Control Z (CP/M  end
>          of file).
> ```

On the `sz`  man page, the description is:

> ```
>   -a, --ascii
>          Convert NL characters in the transmitted file to CR/LF.  This is
>          done by the sender for XMODEM and YMODEM, by  the  receiver  for
>          ZMODEM.
> ```

So, when you're transferring a file from the cloud server to yourself, Xshell is the one responsible for the actual conversion.

Back when I worked in a company that still had some OpenVMS servers, the OpenVMS server administrator said he preferred to do any file format conversions as a separate, explicit step whenever possible. His rationale was (paraphrased) "that's the only way I can be sure of whether or not something has been converted and exactly how the conversion was done." After dealing with line endings and Scandinavian characters in PC8, various old 7-bit national character encodings, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, and finally UTF-8, and conversions between these, I tend to agree with him.

Also, whenever examining character conversion results, I've learned to hex dump any suspicious conversion result and check the characters against an appropriate encoding table. When it's about line endings, you might also use `cat -A` to make the extra `\r`'s visible, or `file` to *describe* the type of line endings used instead of trying to *show* them. Sometimes the conversion does not get applied exactly the way you expect; sometimes the cloud server's text editor, TTY driver or your terminal might be "helpfully" applying another layer of conversion that changes the very thing you're trying to inspect, and making you draw the wrong conclusions.

Comment: Wow. Thank you sincerely for all the details and advice. Sometimes I do think that doing the conversion manually/take another step would be more secure and reliable. Now you just make me more convinced about this. I use `xxd` to dump simple text files on my Ubuntu server and `Hxd` app on Windows.

Comment: I still have some questions on your answer. Firstly, we're using the words `upload` and `download` the same way. The first question is that I always type `rz` on the server prompt when I need to upload a file. So I am wondering how the other method without typing `rz` work. How to do that? You didn't say in the answer. *"..if you just use Xshell's "send file using ZMODEM" function without any preparations at the remote cloud server end. ..."* ,  *"For this to work, the Xshell session to the cloud server must be at command prompt, ready to receive commands."*.

Comment: Then how do I trigger file upload without typing `rz` on server prompt so that the setting in Xshell will be used as you mentioned?

Comment: The second question would be: as you said in the comment, *"In the ZMODEM protocol, the sender specifies the transfer mode (ascii vs. binary) to use. so specifying `--ascii` to the `rz` command does nothing:.."* , then how do I make `Xshell` to send in `-a` mode? You saw the screenshot, I ticked `Send files as ASCII` but the line end conversion doesn't happen. (Well, I am even not sure whether the `Send files as ASCII` option has the same meaning as `-a` for `sz`. I just guess it might be that.)

Comment: The last question is: I am using `Ubuntu` and `apt intall lrzsz` so I think we have the same manpage.  I am getting more confused while thinking of this last question. If the option `-a` only works on the sender's side, aka whom trigger `sz` command, then what's the deal of `-a` option of `rz` command? It states `Convert  files to Unix conventions by stripping carriage returns`. Isn't this a `Windows to Unix ` line ending conversion? Why put `-a` in the doc if it doesn't work on `rz`?

Comment: I don't have Xshell here, but according to its documentation, you might just try selecting File -> Transfer -> Send with ZMODEM or dragging & dropping a local file into Xshell's window. Then it should automatically type in the `rz` command (or whatever is written into the "Upload Command" configuration field) to the remote end for you, and start the transfer. No clue why the `-a` or `--ascii` does not work, maybe some check in the `rz` code is wrong and you must *both* check the `Send files as ASCII` *and* give the `-a` option for `rz` for it to work, or something.

Comment: You are right about the dragging & dropping part. I saw your new comment and tried and it indeed works as you said.

Comment: Basically, I am assuming that the Xfile's `Send files as ASCII` sets the appropriate bit in the ZFILE header when sending a file with ZMODEM, but it might be that the Xfile developer has not actually implemented it and is just re-using the dialog template that was already created for FTP transfers or something.

Comment: I tried serveral combinations before making topmost comments , including check `Send files as ASCII` after typing `rz -a` on the server prompt, it just didn't work. Never mind, really thank you for taking me here. If you happen to find anything interesting in the future, leave me a comment ;P. I would probably stop here for now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ssh requires a separate TCP/IP connection and a remote server daemon to connect to.  Not all systems may have that.

zmodem uses the *existing* connection sending and receiving characters.  This means that all the infrastructure needed is *already in place*.   As you are probably too slow to type the characters expected at the other end, your side needs a program too.  Xshell appears to have that built in so the Zmodel start sequence is recognized directly (or you would have to start the client by hand).